# How to fix the direction of an enemy shooting a player in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I'm trying to make a mage enemy shoot the player with a spell when he is in range. Currently, he shoots the spell projectile at the right time and at the right distance, but for some reason, it fires in the opposite direction of the player relative to the mage. This is the current code. I'm fairly new to Unity, so any feedback/improvements would be appreciated.

```cs
// Variables being used
public float period = 3f;
public GameObject spell;
public GameObject mage;
public GameObject HitBox;
public Transform LaunchOffset;

private float shootingTime;
private Transform playerTransform;


if (Time.time > shootingTime)
{
    shootingTime = Time.time + period;
    Vector3 myPos = new Vector3(LaunchOffset.position.x, LaunchOffset.position.y);
    GameObject projectile = Instantiate(spell, myPos, Quaternion.identity);
    Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(projectile.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>(), mage.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>(), HitBox.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>());
    Vector3 direction = myPos - (Vector3)playerTransform.position;
    projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * spellSpeed;
}
```

Comment: Get the direction the other way round. Eg player-my pos?

Answer (score 1):

Direction of a point towards a target point, is target point's position minus other point's position. So just change that line of code:

```
Vector3 direction = playerTransform.position - myPos;
```

Here is more info: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DirectionDistanceFromOneObjectToAnother.html